# Mongoose: $unshift with findOneAndUpdate is not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, mern

I have this model:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  profileImageURLs: [
    {
      url: {
        type: String,
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

And I have this function that updates the `profileImageURLs` field:

```
const updateProfileImageUrl = async (user_id) => {
  const search_option = {
    user: user_id,
  };
  const update_option = {
    profileImageURLs: {
      $unshift: {
        url: `https://resources/profile_image`,
        current: true,
      },
    },
  };

  const should_return_updated_profile = { new: true };
  const updated_profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
    search_option,
    update_option,
    should_return_updated_profile
  );
  console.log(
    " ~ file: profileServices.js ~ line 1558 ~ updateProfileImageUrl ~ updated_profile",
    updated_profile
  );
};
```

The problem is the it is ignoring the values `url` and `current` in `update_option` and is only creating the `_id` and `date` fields:

```
  profileImageURLs: [ { _id: 635ce632d633392b42c49094, date: 2022-10-29T08:37:06.012Z }]
```

And when I do a second update, instead of adding a new value to the beginning of the array, it creates a new array with the new values. So I have another array with a single object like that.

Any idea what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

I used this instead and it works just fine:

```
  const profile = await Profile.findOne(search_option);
  profile.profileImageURLs.unshift({
    url: profileImageURL,
    current: true,
  });
  const updated_profile = await profile.save();
```